# Angular 6 Universal with ssr production build error

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm new to angular 6 i almost fully completed my app but i' facing some issues with ssr.I followed this tutorial to do ssr [tutorial](https://snipcart.com/blog/angular-seo-universal-server-side-rendering) but i'm facing issues
in building while i run this **npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr** comand i got two folders in in my dist folder one is browser and another is server. while running the command browser build is generated sucessfully but my server build encountered an error like this.
[image]

can any one figueout why this error occured.Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading node and npm to latest version solved the issue